# Ant JUnit task: Is there a difference between on, yes, and true?

Tags: ant, junit

TL;DR: To enable an Ant feature, is there a difference between `on`, `yes`, and `true`?

I cannot find any documentation regarding this matter.  We have some Ant build scripts that seem to randomly pick between: `on` `yes` and `true` to enable various Ant JUnit features.

Example attributes: `fork` and `haltonerror`

Ref: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html:

> The most common way to write an attribute setter is to use a java.lang.String argument. In this case Ant will pass the literal value (after property expansion) to your task. But there is more! If the argument of you setter method is
>
> - boolean, your method will be passed the value true if the value specified in the build file is one of true, yes, or on and false otherwise.

So `yes`, `on` and `true` are the same thing.