# Setting linksource property in NetBeans Maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jfreechart, javadoc

When working with an evolving API, I often use the [`-linksource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#CHDFBBID) option of [`javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html) to add source links to the standard HTML documentation. In the particular case of [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info), I might

- Add `linksource="yes"` to the `"javadoc"` target in `build.xml`, as shown [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html), or
- Add `-linksource` to the NetBeans project properties as an additional `javadoc` property.

As the current version of [`JFreeChart`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart) uses [Maven](https://maven.apache.org), I tried setting `linksource` to `yes` in the action that generates `javadoc`, as shown below.

[image: yes.png]

The resulting documentation had no source links. I haven't used Maven in a while. Where am I going awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. As [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) illustrates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26838521/230513), `ant` treats `yes`, `on` and `true` as the same value. In contrast, your [Netbeans Maven](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html) project uses the [`javadoc:javadoc`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html) plugin, as can be seen under "Execute Goals" for the selected action. To meet the plugin's requirements, simply set the [`linksource`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#linksource) attribute to `true`, as shown below.

[image: true.png]